# Binary classification using 04-zoo.csv data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

In the zoo data, there are several types of each sample.
For making the binary classification, type 0,1,2,3 gets label 0 and type 4,5,6 gets label 1.

It's too hard for me to make split the types into two labels. So, I adjusted the data just adding the labels like below screen capture.

[image]

and I built the model like below.

```py
    import tensorflow as to
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

    zoo = np.loadtxt('~\\data-04-zoo.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
    features = zoo[:, 0:-1]
    labels = zoo[:, [-1]]
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.25, shuffle=True, random_state=77)

    print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
    print('X_test shape:', X_test.shape)
    print('y_train shape:', Y_train.shape)
    print('y_test shape:', Y_test.shape)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=17, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.25, shuffle=True, epochs=20, batch_size=2)
    score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=2)
    print(score)
```

My professor said that model can't be taught.

What's the problem?? I don't know how to adjust the codes.

[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TchHO.png)

Comment: What is the shape of your X_train, Y_train, and test data?

Comment: @RichardX X_train shape: (75, 17)
X_test shape: (26, 17)
y_train shape: (75, 1)
y_test shape: (26, 1)

Comment: Have you tried training your model? That should give you an idea about whether your model works or not.

Comment: @RichardX I added the screen capture the result of the operation the model

Comment: type 0,1,2,3 gets label 0 and type 4,5,6 gets label 1. What do you mean by this? Also, I cant see any label/target field in the above screenshot